# how to search place based on custom properties on mapbox android?

Tags: java, android, sdk, geocoding, mapbox

i am using mapbox SDK and i create style with my own tileset added in the style. The tileset include custom properties such as polygon id, village id, village name, etc. Now i want to make an android application to search place based that custom properties like village id or name, is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Query source features would probably be the first place to look, here's [some documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/map-sdk/overview/query/#query-source-features) for more details.